# I am getting an error when trying to import python-vlc

Tags: python, python-vlc

I want to import the vlc module in a python program.
When trying to use `import vlc`, I face these errors:

```
    dll, plugin_path  = find_lib()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/vlc.py", line 191, in find_lib
    ctypes.CDLL('libvlccore.dylib')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/ctypes/__init__.py", line 373, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: This looks like the middle section of an error. Are there no other relevant lines above or below these?

Comment: Which operating system are you using? Did you install the package correctly? pip3 install python-vlc

Comment: There isnt any more traceback

Comment: I am using MacOS